# Why is this basic "rotate around the origin" failing to work?

Tags: matrix, rotation, shader, direct3d

I've done this a hundred times, but this is my first time with a manually constructed cube made of "sticks", which are 3D lines.  It's constructed around the origin, out 5 from the origin in each of the X, Y, and Z directions.

When I rotate it, I'm still "inside it" and it rotates around me (the camera).  I'm applying a translation and rotation, so I'm stymied as to what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the basic code to rotate the box, by which I mean generate it's world matrix:

```
float rotateX = 0.0f, rotateY = 0.0f, rotateZ = 0.0f;
XMFLOAT4 positionBox = XMFLOAT4(0, 0, -50, 1);   // Camera at origin looking at this
XMMATRIX matrixCubeWorld;

void CALLBACK OnFrameMove( double fTime, float fElapsedTime, void* pUserContext )
{
    auto pCamera = g_GameServices.GetService<CWorldCamera>();

    XMMATRIX translation = XMMatrixTranslationFromVector(XMLoadFloat4(&positionBox));
    XMMATRIX rotation = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ);

    matrixCubeWorld = rotation * translation;

    if (GetKeyState('X') < 0)
        rotateX = RotateAround(rotateX, fElapsedTime);
    if (GetKeyState('Y') < 0)
        rotateY = RotateAround(rotateY, fElapsedTime);
}
```

And when I set up to draw, I use that matrix:

```
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
    V(pd3dImmediateContext->Map(_pVertexShaderVariables, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedResource));
    auto pCB = reinterpret_cast<VSCB3DLineChangesEveryFrame *>(MappedResource.pData);
    pCB->_gWorldViewProj = matrixCubeWorld * pCamera->GetViewMatrix() * pCamera->GetProjMatrix();
    pd3dImmediateContext->Unmap(_pVertexShaderVariables, 0);
    return hr;
```

...and the shader is as simple as can be:

```
VertexShaderOutput Line3DVertexShaderFunction(float3 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR, float2 tex : TEXCOORD0)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    output.position = mul(float4(position, 1), _gWorldViewProj);
    output.color    = color;
    output.tex      = tex;
    return output;
}
```

So do I have a bug or a misunderstanding?  I've tried with the inverse of the translation, thinking that would 'bring it back to the origin before rotating' but didn't improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Transformations look good imho.
Maybe it's due to the fact that 'XMMatrixTranslationFromVector'
takes only 3d-vector as the documentation ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixtranslationfromvector%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) says.

Also make sure that RotateAround function and camera view/proj matrices give correct results.

Best regards.